# Issue in calling VB6 native dll from VB.net Project

Tags: vb.net, vb6, interop, pinvoke

I have a vb6 project in which I use a dll library to do some tasks. For that, I add a module which declares all functions of that library such as:

```
Declare Function myFunction Lib "abcdapi.dll" (ByVal hVar1 As Long, ByVal hVar2 As Long) As Long
```

When I call this function (and many other similar) I'm able to do the work and correct Long pointer is returned. But when I try to do the same thing by VB.net (by importing the same library using dllimport and calling the same function), I get no result. although it does return some pointer but that doesn't produce correct result.

```
Private Const ABCD As String = "abcdapi.dll" 
<DllImport(ABCD)>

Public Shared Function myFunction(ByVal hVar1 As IntPtr, ByVal hVar2 As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
```

When I try to call the above function, it doesn't work. I even tried creating a dll in my vb6 project using the function and try to use imports keyword to call that new dll but that doesn't work either. What could be the issue and how do I make it work.

Comment: Can you show some code that calls the function? How "doesnt it work" from vb.net? Errors, wrong return values, it what?

Comment: the function call is below:
ibOK = TM1ValBoolGet(hUser, voTemp)
In VB.net:Declare Function TM1ValBoolGet Lib "tm1api.dll" (ByVal hUser As Long, ByVal vBool As Long) As Integer 

In vb.net:
<DllImport(TM1APIDLL)>  Public Shared Function TM1ValBoolGet(ByVal hUser As IntPtr, ByVal vBool As IntPtr) As Integer
            End Function

I don't have code of this function so not sure what happens in it but the function details can be seen here:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ctm1/v9r5m0/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.tm1_api.9.5.2.doc/tm1_api_id14631tm1func_tm1valboolget.html

Comment: as per the above link of ibm documentation, this function should return 1 if everything is ok, in vb6 it returns 1 but in vb.net it is returning 91. I have no idea why

Comment: Please edit your post instead of posting code in a comment.  That code is practically unreadable.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway sorry it's proving to be too difficult. the help mentioned on site doesn't seem to work on my system. for formatting the text as code i left 4 spaces as suggested, but didn't work. then I inserted 2 spaces to put a line break, didn't work... I am even trying to write at the rate symbol to inform previous commenter, but that too is not appearing in the comment. what's wrong, i don't know, i'm reading things wrong or too stressed out.. i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The docos you referenced show:

```
TM1IMPORT TM1_BOOL TM1API TM1ValBoolGet(TM1U hUser, TM1V vBool );
```

Is it possible that TM1U and TM1V are defined as 32 bit data types in that API and you are running your .NET code on a 64 bit machine, making your IntPtr a 64 bit data type?  (If the API came with C header files you can see how those data types are defined).  Try recompiling your .NET code to "x86" and try it again.

I just copied this code from your comment above:

> the function call is below:

```
ibOK = TM1ValBoolGet(hUser, voTemp)
```

> In VB.net:  <<< I assume here you meant VB6

```
Declare Function TM1ValBoolGet Lib "tm1api.dll" (ByVal hUser As Long, ByVal vBool As Long) As Integer
```

> In vb.net:

```
<DllImport(TM1APIDLL)> Public Shared Function TM1ValBoolGet(ByVal hUser As IntPtr, ByVal vBool As IntPtr) As Integer 
End Function
```

It is probably a typo, but that return type in your VB6 is not the same as the one in VB.NET.  A VB6 Integer is 16 bits and an Integer in VB.NET is 32 bits.

Comment: I'm compiling my code for x86 environment only and I have a 32 bit machine. That TM1U and TM1V are defined because the website explains the function in reference with C. But you can take a look how the function is declared in VB Api wrapper. (as shown above) Any ideas?

Comment: I see your declarations. The VB6 Long data type is always 32 bit no matter what. But the IntPtr data type is 32 bits on x86 and 64 bits on x64, hence my suggestion of a reason it doesn't work in .NET. Compiling for x86 should prevent that though, so not likely it.

Comment: Thanks @tcarvin I've even converted all Longs to Integer in my vb.net project, and all integers to Int16.. but still doesn't work. I've changed my target machine from 'Any' to x86. But no change. Error still persists.